# "2 views" hardly different that "2 kviews"

Tags: feature-request, design

In the old version of MO, the header of a question was accompanied by a graphic information (this is an example): a huge "2" or "2k" and a tiny "views". Now we see Huge "2" and tiny "views" or "kviews". This way we have lost a clear distinction between widely popular questions with 2000 views and hardly visited ones with only 2 views. These differ by color but my eyes hardly see such difference.

Please revert this feature to the previous format.

Edit: Manishearth provided in his answer a link to a discussion on the same topic: ["kviews" should be "k views"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29544/kviews-should-be-k-views). This is a very old discussion, at that time I was not a member of MO. Since the problem has been solved perfectly then I hope it is still possible now.

Comment: Failing that, one could use a K instead of a k.

Comment: K would help, or may be "KVIEWS" if Huge "2k" is impossible. Two other ideas, if possible: leave the full number 2000 or change the color into something that even my coarse eye would easily distinguish from the grey. Thank you for your attention to this problem, I know this is a detail but often I look into a question only because it has attracted many views and these prove to be more interesting than the average one.

Answer (score -6):

See ["kviews" should be "k views"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29544/kviews-should-be-k-views)

While I agree that "kviews" is confusing, I don't think that the clear distinction is lost. To me, the color stands out:

[image]

You'll probably get used to it :)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I know my eyes are not that good with colors, this doesn't stand out to me.

Comment: Maybe it is my mild colorblindness, but I can't see ANY difference in color between the five images you posted.

Comment: @TomChurch Hmm, oh well. All I can say is that questions with kviews pop out like a sore thumb on most SE sites including MO. But I agree that it should be changed for the better.

Comment: @Manishearth This is probably due to the default settup of the SE software. Justifying from what you wrote here, you know a lot more about SE than I do. May be you would know whom to suggest to fix this "sore thumb" once and for all?

Comment: @AdamPrzezdziecki Jin Yang (Usually Jin, jzy on your meta). He looks out for questions tagged [design] network-wide, so this will probably get some attention. As it is, (IIRC) Jin's going to be working on your site soon -- at least for the chat theme and maybe for all the other design issues.

Comment: @AdamPrzezdziecki To be clear, no need to ping anyone. Jin will see this sooner or later.

Comment: If I look very carefully, I can detect a slight difference in color between the "2 kviews" (a sort of rusty gray) and the other four examples (just plain gray), but the difference is certainly not easily noticeable if I'm not specifically looking for it.